# Функция кляпа

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть в игре функция молчания (кляпа):

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['molcha']) || isset($_POST['prich']) || isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $molcha   = $_POST['molcha'];
    $prichina = $_POST['prich'];
    $login    = $_POST['login'];
    $s        = $molcha * 60;
    $date_    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + $s);
    $date     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $esul     = mysql_query("SELECT `admin`,`moderator` FROM `players_the_game` WHERE 
    `ID`='{$_SESSION['id']}' || `username`='{$_SESSION['user']}'");
    $result   = mysql_fetch_array($esul);
    if ($result['admin'] == 1) {
        $rang = 'Администратор';
    } elseif ($result['moderator'] == 1) {
        $rang = 'Модератор';
    } else {
        $rang = 'Пользовател';
    }
    if ($molcha == 0) {
        $text_msg = ": " . $rang . ": " . $_SESSION[user] . " снял молчу с пользователя " . $login . ",  
    по причине: " . $prichina . "!";
        echo "Вы сняли молчу с пользователя: " . $login . ", по причине: " . $prichina . "!";

    } else {
        $text_msg = ": " . $rang . ": " . $_SESSION[user] . " выдал молчу пользователю " . $login . ",  
    до " . $date_ . ", по причине: " . $prichina . "!";
        echo "Вы выдали молчу пользователю: " . $login . " до " . $date_ . ", по причине:    
    " . $prichina . "! Дата выдачи кляпа: " . $date . "";

    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO `chat` (`date` ,`text` ,`aftor`)VALUES ('$date', '$text_msg', 'Poke-x')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Неизвестная ошибка!");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `players_the_game` SET `molcha`='{$date_}' WHERE      `username`='{$login}' LIMIT 1");
} else {
}
?>
<form method=POST name=mess_chat>
<input class=text_c type=text name=login maxlength=20 style=width:12% placeholder='  пользователю'>
<input class=text_c type=text name=molcha maxlength=20 style=width:12% placeholder=' кол.минут'>
<input class=text_c type=text name=prich maxlength=20 style=width:32% placeholder=' причина '>
<input class=knopka type=submit value=OK>
</form>
```

Есть ещё чат. Как вывести пользователю количество оставших минут до окончание кляпа (молчания), как реализовать?

Comment: про6овал так:

    $kl = $date - $date_;
    $kl_1 = $kl*60;
    echo"Вы 6удете молчать ещё ".$kl_1."минут";

не ра6отает

Comment: Вопрос немного не в тему, но что за игра у Вас реализована на php? или php это только сайт игры?

Comment: на php+mysql+JQuery+Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как я вас понял - то время окончания молчи находится в табл players_the_game в поле molcha.
Если мои предположения верны, то нада сделать запрос

```
"SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(molcha)) as time_sec FROM  `players_the_game`  WHERE `username`=".$login
```

Результат выведет кол-во оставшихся секунд

А вот этот запрос

```
   "SELECT (SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(molcha)))as time_molcha FROM  `players_the_game` WHERE `username`=".$login
```

выведет время молчи в формате HH:MM:SS

Comment: как вывести? 
про6овал так:

    $m = mysql_query("SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(molcha)) as time_sec FROM `players_the_game` WHERE `username`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `passw`='{$_SESSION['pass']}' and `email`='{$_SESSION['email']}' LIMIT 1") or die('О_о');
    $m_ = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
$text = ': вы будете молчат ещё '.$m_[molcha].'секунд';
$query ="INSERT INTO `chat` (`date` ,`text` ,`aftor` ,`to` ,`yes_or_no_private`)VALUES ('$date', '$text', 'Poke-x', '$_SESSION[user]', '1')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Неизвестная ошибка!"); 

Не ра6отает

Comment: уважаемый а вы давно работаетет в MySQl и PHP? Где вы взяли в моем запросе поле molcha, которое и хотите вывести?. Рекомендую уделить некоторое время изучению данной теме) А в моем случае вывод будет как $m_['time_sec']. А второе $m_ = mysql_fetch_array($resul) -нада заменить на $m_ = mysql_fetch_array($m);

Comment: | 2012-08-18 19:29:51 | [Poke-x to Riolu]: вы будете молчат ещё -5933секунд[x]
| 2012-08-18 19:29:06 | [Poke-x to Riolu]: вы будете молчат ещё -5978секунд[x]
| 2012-08-18 19:28:44 | Poke-x: Администратор: Riolu выдал молчу пользователю Riolu, до 2012-08-18 21:08:44, по причине: проверка...![x]

Comment: всмысле все работает?
если да не забудте отметить правильный ответ)

Comment: да но секунды уходят в минус

Comment: ну так сделайте вот так запрос $m = mysql_query("SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(molcha)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) as time_sec FROM `players_the_game` WHERE `username`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `passw`='{$_SESSION['pass']}' and `email`='{$_SESSION['email']}' LIMIT 1") or die('О_о');

Comment: Да кстати, хотел спрасить - а как вы будете снимать молчи?

Comment: спс все ра6отает =)

    <?
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
    if($result[molcha]==$date or $result[molcha]<$date){}else{
    $text = ': вы будете молчат ещё '.$m_[time_sec].'секунд';
    $query ="INSERT INTO `chat` (`date` ,`text` ,`aftor` ,`to` ,`yes_or_no_private`)VALUES ('$date', '$text', 'Poke-x', '$_SESSION[user]', '1')";
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Неизвестная ошибка!"); 

    }